# Why does std::list::pop_front seem slow for large lists?

Tags: c++, stdlist

I'm trying to limit the size of a list by deleting nodes from the front before appending new nodes to the end. I expected the speed to be constant regardless of list size, but I see longer execution times for larger lists. Am I implementing it wrong, or is pop_front actually not constant time?

The following code executes with these results:

```
$ time ./testlist 2 1000000
MAX is 2
NUM is 1000000
DELETED 999998

real    0m0.835s

$ time ./testlist 10 1000000
MAX is 10
NUM is 1000000
DELETED 999990

real    0m1.070s

$ time ./testlist 100 1000000
MAX is 100
NUM is 1000000
DELETED 999900

real    0m3.612s

$ time ./testlist 1000 1000000
MAX is 1000
NUM is 1000000
DELETED 999000

real    0m28.838s
```

The source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>

int deletes=0;
std::list<int> l;
void insert(int x, size_t maxsize) {
    if (l.size() == maxsize)
    {
        l.pop_front();
        deletes++;
    }
    l.push_back(x);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t v = atoi(argv[1]);
    size_t n = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << "MAX is " << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NUM is " << n << std::endl;
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        insert(i, v);
    }
    std::cout << "DELETED " << deletes << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a ring buffer? It's a zillion times more efficient. https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/ring-buffers-and-queues/

Comment: Which platform, compiler and C++ version are you using ? C++98 allows std::list.size() to be linear.  Try keeping the count yourself without calling `l.size()` and re-run the test.

Comment: I can't really put my finger on it (I blame it on the Christmas party last night) but something about your test program doesn't feel quite right. If you want to test the performance of just `pop_front` then I suggest you do a specific test program for just that. Use e.g. [`gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) (or [`clock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html)) for timing just that part of the code.

Comment: Probably push_back after pop_front has to search to the last element of list, and this take time. What wrote nos is also correct

Comment: Btw. using `deque` makes this O(1) here (GCC 4.9.x)

Comment: Are you timing an optimized build?  If not, then your observations are meaningless.

Comment: Another thing is that until the code reach the maximum number of elements, a new structure has to be allocated each time a new elemento is added.

Comment: @LPs no, this is not allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 6):

`std::list::size()` takes linear time (GCC 4.9.2), even in optimized builds. Use this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include <deque>

int deletes=0;
int size=0;
std::list<int> l;
void insert(int x, size_t maxsize) {
    if (size == maxsize)
    {
        l.pop_front();
        deletes++;
    size--;
    }
    size++;
    l.push_back(x);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t v = atoi(argv[1]);
    size_t n = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << "MAX is " << v << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NUM is " << n << std::endl;
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        insert(i, v);
    }
    std::cout << "DELETED " << deletes << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Notice: `deque` might be faster (if the implementation uses an array, else they're the same, however, `deque` provides the same performance as `list` with this optimization — YMMV)

Addendum: C++11 does not seem to provide leeway for a O(n) `size()` as it says in 23.2.1 *General container requirements*:

> Expression: a.size()
>
> Complexity: constant

Prior to C++11 it said "constant or linear" in this place, which caused your performance issue in this specific case.

GCC 5.0 will fix this issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49561